# Wallpaper won't stay

Tags: desktop-background, reboot

I'm a new Lubuntu user (LXLE to be precise). I want to know why doesn't my wallpaper stay after a reboot? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't stay ?

Comment: I set the wallpaper trough right clicking the desktop and clicking desktop preferences. The wallpaper is applied but when I shut down the pc and power it on again, the wallpaper resets to a random default wallpaper. I checked everywhere and nobody seems to have this problem. Please help me as I'm really in a pinch here.

Comment: Is the image on your desktop, home or download directory? Right click on the dekstop, show desktop settings, set to Default Desktop Layout, click open and navigate to the photo. Please ensure that the wallpaper is image, not slideshow. Apply this image and restart the PC. Does it stay like so? Please keep me tuned!

Comment: Did you dual boot (with Windows)? It may be that you dual booted and the wallpaper image is in the Windows partition. It disappears every reboot since your Windows partition isn't automatically mounted when you start-up.

Comment: The image is in my ../pictures/wallpapers directory, where the other default ubuntu wallpapers are. The image is not a slideshow. And I have no setting for Default Desktop Layout, I only have desktop preferences which bring me directly to the menu where I can change wallpapers. I have already messed with the configs in pcmanfm setting every possible one to use the one I want, but when I log on, the picture is shown only briefly, then it reverts to default...

Comment: I seem to have solved it, somehow... I needed to delete every wallpaper in /home/gal/Pictures/Wallpapers and put only the one that I want in there. It seems the system changes the wallpaper randomly from the selection of those in the Wallpapers folder. For now it works, but I need a more permanent fix, I don't want to keep deleting/inserting old and new wallpapers in the folder.

Comment: @SKYTREADER Sorry I haven't seen your comment. No, the wallpapers are in my /home/gal/pictures/wallpaper directory. And yes I have a windows dual boot.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is

1. Copy file to your Home directory (partition of Ubuntu)
2. add execute permission to that image you are using by

> chmod 751 filename

It won't change when you restart!